# How to add data from another DataFrame, where differing granularities of dates match?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

Hello I am newish to python and pandas

I have two DataFrames, one on a higher timeframe with Daily granularity, and one on a lower timeframe with hourly granularity. What I want to do is append the 'trend' data from the higher timeframe to the lower time frame where the day is the same. I'm having some trouble. My DataFrames have datetime index and look something like this:

Higher time frame:

```
 time                  state
2015-06-03 22:00:00    bullish
2015-06-04 22:00:00    bullish
2015-06-05 22:00:00    bearish
2015-06-06 22:00:00    bullish
2015-06-07 22:00:00    bullish
2015-06-08 22:00:00    bullish
```

Lower time frame:

```
time                   state
2015-06-05 05:00:00    bullish
2015-06-05 09:00:00    bullish
2015-06-05 13:00:00    bullish
2015-06-05 17:00:00    bullish
2015-06-07 21:00:00    bullish
2015-06-08 01:00:00    bullish
```

And my desired result would look like this:

```
time                   state     trend
2015-06-05 05:00:00    bullish   bearish
2015-06-05 09:00:00    bullish   bearish
2015-06-05 13:00:00    bullish   bearish
2015-06-05 17:00:00    bullish   bearish
2015-06-07 21:00:00    bullish   bullish
2015-06-08 01:00:00    bullish   bullish
```

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
d = {'state_x':'state','state_y':'trend'}
df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='time', direction='forward').rename(columns=d)

print (df)
                 time    state    trend
0 2015-06-05 05:00:00  bullish  bearish
1 2015-06-05 09:00:00  bullish  bearish
2 2015-06-05 13:00:00  bullish  bearish
3 2015-06-05 17:00:00  bullish  bearish
4 2015-06-07 21:00:00  bullish  bullish
5 2015-06-08 01:00:00  bullish  bullish
```